# How to edit UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have created an instance of `UITableViewController` and I have some data from Firebase displaying in cells; no problem there. But I would like to add a text field (for comments) and a button (for posting that comment) on the bottom of the `UITableViewController` (and NOT `UITableView`). The reason why I chose `UITableViewController` instead of `UIViewController` and then adding a `UITableView` is because if I do the latter the data would not display in my cells. So, I would like to know how to edit/or add elements to the bottom of the `UITableViewController`.

I have tried programmatically adding a text field and button but it would not work, and if I added a table view to `UIViewController` I just could not get the data to display correctly from Firebase.

```
func setupInputComponents() {
    //x,y,w,h
    let containerView = UIView()
    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive=true
    containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive=true
    containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive=true

    //x,y,w,h
    let sendButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    sendButton.setTitle("Post", for: .normal)
    sendButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //klici funkcijo za gumb
    sendButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePost), for: .touchUpInside)
    containerView.addSubview(sendButton)
    sendButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    sendButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    sendButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    sendButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    //x,y,w,h
    containerView.addSubview(commentInputTextField)
    commentInputTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    commentInputTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    commentInputTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sendButton.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    commentInputTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor).isActive = true        
}
```

I expect the table view to be populated with the data (comments) from Firebase and the text field with a button to be placed on the bottom of the phone screen.

EDIT:
this is the code if I try with UIViewController and tableView:

```
    import UIKit
    import Firebase
    class CommentDoOrDieViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messages.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "commentTableCell", for: indexPath) as? CommentsTableViewCell else {fatalError("error")}
    let message = messages[indexPath.row]
    cell.komentLabela?.text = message.msg
    return cell
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tabela.dataSource = self
    tabela.delegate = self
    showComments()
}

struct Message {
    var msg: String?
    var id: String?
}
var messages = [Message]()

var productId = ""
var productName = ""

@IBOutlet weak var tabela: UITableView!




func showComments(){
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("productComments").child(productId)
    ref.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        print(snapshot)

        if let slovar = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
            var a = Message()
            a.msg = slovar["comment"] as? String
            a.id = slovar["userId"] as? String
            self.messages.append(a)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tabela.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Comment: `UIViewController` would be a better choice in case you want to have anything else except the tableView in the controller's view.

Comment: I think you can not add sticky view (or button etc.) to bottom of your `UITableViewController`. You should use `UIViewController` and create `UITableView`.

Comment: I see no reason why a `UITableView` in a `UIViewController` would not work when a `UITableViewController` would, and you're much better off using the former. Perhaps you could elaborate on what happened when you tried using a `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can do this correctly, since in case of `UITableViewController` `self.view` is `UITableView`. 
You can try to do this by `header` or `footer` of `view` or replace `UITableViewController` with `UIViewController`. Add `UITableView` at the top of screen and textField and button at the bottom

**EDITED**

in the case of `UIViewController` be sure that you attached `UITableViewDataSource`

[image]

Comment: I know and that was my first chooice, but I just could not show the data in the UITableView, I've spent more than 2 days trying to figure it out and than I gave up and used UITableViewController and had it working in few minutes no problem.

Comment: Have you attached `UITabableViewDataSource` of `UITableView`?

Comment: Yes, I went through 5 or 6 youtube tutorials and few articles on stackoverflow and everything seemed okey but it just did not work. I'll try again from the begining and we'll see how it turns out

Comment: I updated my answer, if you did everything what on image it should work. if not, add debug breakpoint on `numberOfRowsInSection` and check number of items

Comment: I see, thank you very much, I will try that and hopefully it works. Thanks again for really quick response

Answer (score 0):

Does the number of cells change or is it constant. If it's constant you could try creating a text view in the last displayed cell along with a button and everything else you need there. A good way of doing this is creating two classes, one for the normal cells and another for the last cell with a text view. If you number of cells changes I think you could still create the classes but I'm not sure how you would make sure the cell stays at the bottom.

Using this method the code is more manageable and makes customization much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Might be this below solution can help...
try to put the below code above the code where you are reloading table(in showComments()).

```
tabela.dataSource = self
tabela.delegate = self
```

Comment: Wow, this actually worked. Thank You very very much, you are a lifesaver :) I have to say I don't understand why I have to put delegate and datasource in showComments(), but as long it works I am happy!

Comment: Thank God my First answer help some one.. The reason is when you call your delegates upon the Didload() method it call it first and then it also calls the delegate function so it works parallel, on first your message array was empty thats why it wasn't showing any thing.